# How to Access Number of Views for Pages on Data Center (On-prem) Confluence?

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

I am working with Confluence Data Center in an on-premises environment and I'm looking for a way to access the number of views for specific pages programmatically. I've been searching through the Confluence documentation, and even though there is an API endpoint for the Cloud version, I haven't found a clear solution for Data Center installations.

I appreciate any insights or code snippets that can point me in the right direction. Thank you!